# SLA on JIRA Cloud?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to add SLA (Service Level Agreement) on JIRA Cloud? 
I want to add SLA to each ticket right now I don't find any option on Jira cloud. So I'm looking for add/plugin. I did some research but I don't find any add-ons related to Jira Cloud. Some plugins are available but those plugins cannot support Jira cloud.

I stuck here it would be nice if someone suggests any ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jira Service Desk, they have built in SLAs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've already found the answer, as this question is quite old. But maybe someone else will look for the solution like this.

So, the answer is yes. You can install plugins for Jira (you can easily find them on Atlassian Marketplace). Among the plugins I would recommend trying is **SLA Time and Report for Jira**. This add-on can be used for Jira Cloud, Jira Core, Jira Service Management. And it has wide functionality and is easy-to-use. You can find it [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220741?utm_source=Stackoverflow&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=Comment_sla-on-jira-cloud_20220815).

Hope this will be helpful for someone :)